# LVM - Reducing COW size down to maximum usable size

Tags: linux, backup, lvm, snapshot

I am doing snapshots on an LVM Volume. It works, but since a few minutes I do get a warning message.

The command is:

> sudo lvcreate -s /dev/$VG/$LV -n $SNAP_NAME $VS 2>>$LOG

The VG has enough space for a new LV. However the system issues a warning:

> Reducing COW size 30.00 GiB down to maximum usable size 24.10 GiB

What does it mean, and why is this suddendly apearing?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the reason. COW means (copy on write) and indicates that the lv volume size is 24G but the snapshot command used creates 30G.